# Disable last checkbox multiple choice required

Tags: javascript, jquery

**Scenario :**

I have a vote page, you have to select 3 of 4 candidates from the list.

**Needs :**

I need to make the last checkbox disabled after checking 3 of them (4).

**Code :**

HTML

```
<input class="cb" type="checkbox" name="condidate" value="1" onchange="cbChange(this)" />
<input class="cb" type="checkbox" name="condidate" value="2" onchange="cbChange(this)"/>
<input class="cb" type="checkbox" name="condidate" value="3" onchange="cbChange(this)"/>
<input class="cb" type="checkbox" name="condidate" value="4" onchange="cbChange(this)"/>
```

JS

```
function cbChange(obj) {
    var cbs = document.getElementsByClassName("cb");
    for (var i = 0; i < cbs.length - 3; i++) {
        cbs[i].disabled = true;
    }
    obj.disabled = false;
}
```

**Question :**

How Can I make the last choice disabled after selecting the 3 others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to call cbChange on click event of checkboxes.

```js
   
function cbChange(obj) {
    var cbs = document.getElementsByClassName("cb");
    var checkCount = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < cbs.length; i++) {
        if (cbs[i].checked === true)
  checkCount++;
        cbs[i].disabled = false;
    }
    if (checkCount >= 3){
     for (var i = 0; i < cbs.length; i++) {
  if (cbs[i].checked === false)
   cbs[i].disabled = true;
     }
    }
}
```

```html
    <input class="cb" type="checkbox" name="condidate" value="1" onclick="cbChange(this)"/>
    <input class="cb" type="checkbox" name="condidate" value="2" onclick="cbChange(this)"/>
    <input class="cb" type="checkbox" name="condidate" value="3" onclick="cbChange(this)"/>
    <input class="cb" type="checkbox" name="condidate" value="4" onclick="cbChange(this)"/>
```

Comment: If `checkCount > 3`,there won't be any *to* disable.

Comment: If I uncheck a box after I've checked 3, the 4th stays disabled.

Answer (score 1):

When one of the checkboxes has changed, count the number that are unchecked.  If there is only one, you can disable it; otherwise, if one is disabled, it must be re-enabled.